# Can’t download embedded audio

Tags: websites

This audio sample that I’m trying to download: https://www.audiotool.com/sample/hard_spinz_-_808 doesn’t appear to be listed when viewing the source code. I’ve looked over the whole page multiple times, tried inspect element as well, but I still can’t find a link to the embedded audio. This goes for all the other samples on the site.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome:

1. `More Tools -> Developer Tools`
2. Within developer tools, click on the `Network` tab at the top
3. Within the `Network` tab, click on `Media`
4. Click the play button
5. An entry named `preview.mp3` should show up in the table
6. Right click on `preview.mp3`, click `Open in New Tab`, then right click on the audio player and click `Save audio as...`